# Retirar espaços vazios Laravel + webscraping

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

Estou realizando um `webscraping` da seguinte forma:

```php
$url = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=XXXXXXXX&processo.numero=XXXXXXX';
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$movimentacao = $crawler->filter('tbody td')->each(function ($node) {
    return  explode('Movimentação', $node->text())[0];
});

$descricao1 = explode('Juntada', $movimentacao[2]);
\Log::alert(trim($movimentacao[2]));
dd();
```

Estou trazendo as informações que necessito, porém se eu aplicar um `dd` para analisar as informações de `$movimentacao[2]`, me é exibido da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei aplicar o `trim` e o `str_replace`, porém sem sucesso. Alguém saberia uma forma de retirar **esses espaços vazios** de uma forma eficiente?
Grato

Comment: Vi que tem tabulação, acho que tu pode remover a tabulação da seguinte maneira: `trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string))` ou tu pode usar esse aqui: `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);`

Comment: Ele realmente esta a tirar as tabulações , porem o espaços permanecem...

Comment: Mesmo usando esse comando aqui? `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);`

Comment: Foi perfeitamente... pratico e rápido. Grato

Comment: Aceita minha resposta lá :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente usar esse comando:

```php
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: fiz da seguinte maneira:
```php
trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string));
preg_replace('/\n+/', '', $string);

```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @BetiniO.Heleno Nesse caso, vc poderia fazer `preg_replace('/[\t\n]+/', '', $string)` - assim já remove `\t` e `\n` de uma vez.